# Make a object rotate back to origin in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a beginner with THREE.js and currently have a animation that spins a 3D model around its Y axis but for the website I am creating I need to rotate it back to origin during the timespan of 90 frames. I have tried using a various different code snippets but the problem is that it seems to work half the time and the other half it totally messes it up. I believe that it messes up more if I let it spin for a while.

Here is my current code for the rotation:

```
//angle
    angle = ((room.rotation.y * 180) / Math.PI) % 360;
    total_deg = room.rotation.y;

//for calculating the lap:
    if(angle > 0) {
        positiv = true;
    } else {
        positiv = false;
    }
    if(angle < last_angle) {
        direction = "down";
    } else {
        direction = "up";
    }
    if(direction == "up" && positiv == true) {
        lap = 1;
    } else if(direction == "down" && positiv == true) {
        lap = 2;
    } else if(direction == "down" && positiv == false) {
        lap = 3;
    } else if(direction == "up" && positiv == false) {
        lap = 4;
    }
    if(last_lap == 4 && lap == 1) {
        room.rotation.y = 0;
    }
    last_angle = ((room.rotation.y * 180) / Math.PI) % 360;

//rotating it back depending on what lap it currently is on

    if(lap == 4) {
        room.rotation.y += -total_deg / 90;
    }
    if(lap == 3) {
        room.rotation.y += -(Math.PI - Math.abs(total_deg)) / 90;
    }
    if(lap == 2) {
        room.rotation.y += (Math.PI - Math.abs(total_deg)) / 90;
    } else {
        room.rotation.y -= total_deg / 90;
    }
//reset the rotation when the room has spun a lap - don't know why this is works but seems to fix some of the rotation problems

    if(last_lap == 4 && lap == 1) {
        room.rotation.y = 0;
    }
```

Have been stuck with this problem for days so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using a Quaternion of the objects first rotation and rotating to that later. This example was very helpful: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_math_orientation_transform

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm understanding your objective properly but to me it seems that there may be some confusion with degrees and radians as the units.  Three.js uses radians, but I'm seeing `360` in your code which I'm unsure about.

Anyway this code seems like what you're trying to do, notice how it divides `2 pi` (one rotation in radians) into 90 frames.

```
var i=0;
function update( event ) {

//angle
    if(i++<90){
        this.rotation.y += 2*Math.PI/90;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Isn't this code rotating my object 360 degrees? I am trying to rotate the object back to 0 degrees but because of my animation  my room will be at a random rotation value when the function is activated.

Comment: So are you saying that if `room` is at some arbitrary `rotation.y` value and you set it back to 0 that it doesn't go back to the original rotation?  If so, I would first simplify the code because you should be able to repro that with much less code and then report it as a bug.

Comment: No, it just makes it rotate 360 degrees. The problem is that my animation makes the cube spin and because of this the rotation will be random when the script is activated. Something that almost works is this:     object.rotation.y += (0- room.rotation.y) / 90; but the thing is that it seems to exist two zero points in the objects rotation so this script rotates the object to the back half of the time.